# I need a hand lining 3 images up together side by side

Tags: image, positioning

I am creating a website about UFC and need help with my image positioning I have 3 images and want to place them in a horizontal arrangement across the screen but am having trouble doing this.I have created a div around each of the images to try and position them but cannot seem to get the result that I want, any help would be great.

```
HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="website.html">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="topfightercss.css">

<h1><u>Top Fighters</u></h1>

</head>

<body>



<div id="demetrious">
<img src="dem.png" alt="Demetrious Johnson">  <p> Demetrious Johnson is the 
rank 1 pound for pound fighter in UFC,<br>he is from Kentucky USA and is 
aged 31 and stands at 5'3 (160cm)<br>he weights 56kg (125lb) and has a reach 
of 66" with a leg reach of 34".<br>He has a record of 27 wins 2 losses and 1 
draw and is the curent<br> flyweight champion. </p>    
</div>

<div id="connor">   
<img scr="connor.png"  alt="Connor Mcgegor">  
</div>

<div id="daniel">
<img scr="daniel.png" alt="Daniel Cormier">    
</div>  

</body>

</html>


CSS

html {
background: url(pg2background.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;   
}

h1 {
color: aqua;
text-align: center;
font-size:24pt;
}

.demetrious {
position: relative;
top: 8px;
left: 12px;
width: 450px;
height: 300px;
opacity: 0.3;
}

p {
color: aliceblue;    
}

.connor {
position: center;
top: 8px;
right:12px; 
}

.daniel {
position: relative;

}
```

Comment: Use a table to hold the elements in.

Comment: Add `width` and `height` attribute to the images and remove other styling and the wrapper `div`: `<img scr="daniel.png" alt="Daniel Cormier" width="50" height="50"'><img scr="daniel.png" alt="Daniel Cormier" width="50" height="50"'><img scr="daniel.png" alt="Daniel Cormier" width="50" height="50"'>`

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a container `div` with class `.container` with a fixed width of x pixels, x = 3 * image width, because you have three images. Only use this if you want the images to stay horizontally aligned when the browser window is smaller than the width of 3x

```
.container{
    width: x px;
}
```

Then give a shared class to your image divs, let's call it `.imgClass`. Now turn them to float;

```
.imgClass{
    float:left;
}
```

EDIT: This means your `topfightercss.css` css file should include something like this:

```
.container{
    width: 300 px; //Three times 100px = 300px
}
.imgClass{
    float:left;
    width: 100px; //All pictures are 100px wide. Not required.
}
```

And your html file:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="imgClass"> <img><p>...</p> </div> <!-- demetrious -->
  <div class="imgClass"> <img><p>...</p> </div> <!-- connor -->
  <div class="imgClass"> <img><p>...</p> </div> <!-- daniel -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hi tanks for the reply but i am relatively new to coding and do not understand some of these terms would you be able to help a little more please?